# Pool JVM memory across multiple machines

Tags: java, jvm

I have a [Java project](https://github.com/entangledloops/semiprime) that requires massive amounts of memory to perform a type of heuristic search process. In principle, to compute an arbitrary solution to a problem may require essentially unbounded RAM, but in practice I know that real-world instances can sometimes be solved on the order of terabytes (currently cached on physically connected disks).

**Does there exist an open or closed source project to virtualize RAM across multiple JVM's running on different machines?**

Currently, I can host local searches running on multiple clients and coordinate them through a server. However, this is not what I wish to accomplish.

In order for my problem to be solved in a mathematically consistent fashion, the primary function must occur in a single-threaded paradigm using virtualized memory pooled across the sum of all client machines. I am willing to write such a virtualization layer myself, but want to see if anyone is aware of an existing solution, open or closed source.

Most standard cloud solutions are inadequate for this task as they tend to limit the accessible memory ~1TB and also cost more than I can afford.

Comment: Have you checked the Amazon EC2 x1.32xlarge instance? It comes with nearly 2TB of DDR4 RAM, plus 2x ~2TB SSD local storage, in case you need that cache you mentioned. As of right now, it's a bit above $13/h "on-demand" pricing. If you accept the risk of having your server terminated at any moment, the current "spot" pricing is at about $1.50/h. Does that help?

Comment: It's simply insufficient. Solutions may be found from 10-20 TB or even greater. I'm also looking for the distributed approach so that my friends and my numerous devices can all contribute for free.

Comment: Oh, I see! It's way larger scale than I imagined! Sorry for that. Have you checked Hazelcast then? I've successfully used it a long time ago... good luck!

Comment: Hazelcast is more in line with what I want, but their "massive" examples make me hesitate as they are a bit small for my needs. Thanks, though.

Comment: Do you actually need all the data in memory at once? How about using file-backed virtual memory and a fast enough SSD raid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terracotta had a distributed shared memory pool which might get you close to what you want, depending on the details.

There are also a number of memory virtualization products that sound similar to what you are looking for.  ScaleMP, Wombat Data Fabric, and RNA networks should be reviewed for suitability.

Honestly, if you could rework your algorithm to handle an Apache Spark style of processing, I think you'd get better results, but assuming you must have a number of machines providing ram, consider making that RAM no-volitile and shifting it into a Hadoop / Spark type processing (in Hadoop the ram fragments really are fragments of the solution across disk, in Apache Spark, they are the same, but intelligently cached in real RAM).

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at those. If they are suitable, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @EntangledLoops Thank you, but "must all be in ram" is a pretty tall order.  Back when I did "distributed architecture" (really distributed processing) of seismic for Halliburton (and their clients) we got requests like this all the time.  The better answer typically was "restructure the algorithm" to scale, not restructure the systems to simulate one giant computer.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, it can be cached to disk offline, but the mathematical model cannot be distributed for fundamental reasons that would violate invariants. Although I am experimenting with this as well, I went to test the "pure" approach to a maximum before the more obvious divide-and-conquer-without-guarantees version.

Comment: If I could do seismic analysis and fault detection, both which have a very high degree of wavelet entanglement, to the point where you require the entire trace in ram, and all the neighboring traces to perform the fault detection, and I could chunk it up such that incremental processing could occur without the entire data set in ram at the same time, I imagine you could probably find a way to look up the numbers you need in order too :)

Comment: It can be broken up, I just don't want to detail the whole thing here. Suffice it to say that it can't be parallelized easily b/c out-of-order node expansion would violate the underlying model, so offloading work (do-able) must be buffered until that node is properly reached, and a host of complications arise. There are numerous alternate approaches and so on, I'm just wondering if a simple virtual-RAM API exists with a client-server model.

Comment: I think ScaleMP is close to what I want, approaching the limits of what I'm willing to attempt in-memory for now. Thanks for your input and feel free to post any more solutions that pop into your head.

Comment: @EntangledLoops Fully understand not wanting to go into the details.  Just keep in mind that RAM lookups typically take a few nanoseconds; but, when you start talking about distributed RAM, you have locking, and generally network latency.  The locking can easily take 10,000 times the memory lookup, and the network latency can easily take 100,000 times or more the typical RAM latency.   This means you "distributed memory" solution might start off being 100,000 times slower than a single machine (but it will scale) :)

Comment: Yup. Willing to wait the extra ticks (or hours/days) to see if a few particular instances could be solved with minimal API modification and risk breaking what I have, which is maintained in my spare time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Chronicle Map, Queue or Bytes to utilise virtual memory larger than main memory in Java. 
All these solution support memory mapped data in a JVM many times main memory.

They can be shared across JVMs on the same machine with native memory access speed in each one.  The latencies are typically sub-micro-second for small records in memory. Most data grid solution have a sub-milli-second access for reads/writes.

Chronicle Map is a key value store, the largest any client uses is 10 TB on one machine.

Chronicle Queue is a journal which is good for sequential read/write and the largest is 100 TB.

You can use Chronicle Bytes to share an ever growing memory mapped file. You can have multiple files which are 100+ TB.

All are Apache 2.0 open source.

To share data access across multiple machines, you can use Chronicle Engine for distributed access.

Disclaimer: I helped write these modules.

Comment: Hey that's great info, thanks!